# Display PDF in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, pdf

I am following this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf

I got the entire raw pdf data from backend so I was trying with code below.

```
<ReactPDF file={renderPdf}/>
```

But it displayed "Failed to load PDF file." I don't wish to save any file in local. The best approach is the display the pdf with the raw data provided by backend.

In terminal, it logged the error:

```
URIError: Failed to decode param '/%PDF-1.4%%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%20ReportLab%20Generated%20PDF%20document%20http://www.reportlab.com1%200%20obj%3C%3C/F1%202%200%20R%20/F2%203%200%20R%20/F3%207%200%20R%3E%3Eendobj2%200%20obj%3C%3C/BaseFont%20/Helvetica%20/Encoding%20/WinAnsiEncoding%20/Name%20/F1%20/Subtype%20/Type1%20/Type%20/Font%3E%3Eendobj3%200%20obj%3C%3C/BaseFont%20/Helvetica-Bold%20/Encoding%20/WinAnsiEncoding%20/Name%20/F2%20/Subtype%20/Type1%20/Type%20/Font%3E%3Eendobj4%200%20obj%3C%3C/BitsPerComponent%208%20/ColorSpace%20/DeviceRGB%20/Filter%20[%20/ASCII85Decode%20/FlateDecode%20]%20/Height%20480%20/Length%2036803%20/SMask%205%200%20R%20%20%20/Subtype%20/Image%20/Type%20/XObject%20/Width%20640%3E%3EstreamGb%22-V'
```

Comment: what does `renderPdf` look like?

Comment: @DanO %PDF-1.4
%���� ReportLab Generated PDF document http://www.reportlab.com
1 0 obj
<<
/F1 2 0 R /F2 3 0 R /F3 7 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/BaseFont /Helvetica /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Name /F1 /Subtype /Type1 /Type /Font
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/BaseFont /Helvetica-Bold /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Name /F2 /Subtype /Type1 /Type /Font
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/BitsPerComponent 8 /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB /Filter [ /ASCII85Decode /FlateDecode ] /Height 480 /Length 36803 /SMask 5 0 R 
  /Subtype /Image /Type /XObject /Width 640
>>
stream.....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

it looks like you're passing the PDF data directly to the `<ReactPDF>` component as the value of the `file` prop.  But according to [the docs](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf#props) you need to use an object containing a `data` property:

```
<ReactPDF
  file={{
    data: renderPdf
  }}
/>
```

it seems you can also set `file` to an object containing a `url` property, to let ReactPDF fetch the pdf from your backend by itself, if that's easier:

```
<ReactPDF
  file={{
    url: 'http://www.example.com/sample.pdf'
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Tried with first option with data: {renderPdf} which will trigger error. 2nd option is not possible since it will trigger a get request, while my backend perform some sort of authorization which will send a POST request to retrieve the pdf

Comment: @MervynLee for the latter you'd probably need to use a csrf token for it to be accepted.

Answer (score 48):

If you goal is just to view the pdf in your application, the easiest way is using the object tag in HTML. You don't need to import any libraries and works most of the browsers. But this is lack of customization and styles.

```
  <object data="http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
      <p>Alternative text - include a link <a href="http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf">to the PDF!</a></p>
  </object>
```

Comment: this is perfect! thans

Comment: This works just fine when you just need to embed a PDF, thanks for sharing this answer!

Comment: iOS browsers have a bug that prevents scrolling with this object embed approach

Answer (score 11):

**Try this**

```
<object width="100%" height="400" data="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" type="application/pdf">   </object>
```

Comment: it downloads. doesn't render.

Comment: ohh it renders...sweet

Comment: @NoopurPhalak No!! It didn't render. 

For me this package did the job! https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cyntler/react-doc-viewer

Original Reference: 
https://youtu.be/E0aK6CKsSNg?si=3YTzshMtVsM-alVs

Sorry for confusing language in previous comment

Comment: @AjitTStephen It does render the PDF...it worked for me. Here is my code: ```<object width="100%"  height="100%" data={resume.resume}  type="application/pdf" />```

Here resume is the google cloud storage link to the PDF.

Comment: ohh...my links were... aws s3. That would matter ? @NoopurPhalak

Comment: @AjitTStephen Don't think that show matter...

Comment: @AjitTStephen Notice the self closing tag in my code. May be that is the issue. The answer has a separate closing tag. I am just speculating here...

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem. I convert the binary data that I received from backend into ArrayBuffer.

```
axios.post(//fire your API).then(response =>
        (response.status === 200? response.data : null))
    .then(pdfdata => {
        var len = pdfdata.length;
        var bytes = new Uint8Array( len );
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            bytes[i] = pdfdata.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        const renderPdf = bytes.buffer
```

Then I actually assign bytes.buffer to renderPDF to perform the rendering. Now it is working flawlessly!

In rendering html from react,

```
import PDF from 'react-pdf-scroll'
<PDF file={renderPdf} scale={1.3} pages={Infinity} />
```

Comment: Hi @MervynLee - Can you please post the full code for your solution?

Comment: Hi @JJHolloway, I have posted the code for logic and rendering part in react, anything else?

Comment: Thanks @MervynLee -- did you come across an issue where it just says "Loading PDF file..."  and never loads the PDF?

Comment: @JJHolloway do you mind show the response content returned by server?

Comment: The library react-pdf-scroll has been deprecated according to the npm website https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf-scroll

Answer (score 1):

if your data that is returned from the backend is in the format of buffer then you can set the file info with a parsed JSON object that react-pdf can configure.

```
file={{data: JSON.parse(renderPDF).data}}
```

This will render your PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack";
```

**That will fix your problem. It worked for me**

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the answers posted above this works when using a pdf string

```
<object data={`data:application/pdf;base64,${base64_pdf_string}`} type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
      <p>Alternative text</p>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';

          <div style={{marginLeft:"27%"}}>
            <Document file={fileUrl} onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess} >
              <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
            </Document>
            <p style={{marginLeft:"27%"}}>
              Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}
            </p>
          </div>
```

This will load your pdf make you give the proper URL or data and check https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf

Answer (score -1):

This is a very old issue causing pdf to get hidden on mobile devices.

Ive tried

```
<object width="100%" height="400" data="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

Even this doesn't work

Finally found a working solution

```
<iframe src={pdf_url} />
```

Hope This works.

Nice day coding!

Answer (score -1):

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=YOUR_PDF_URL&embedded=true" frameborder="0" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>
```

In the above iframe, in the src (replace YOUR_PDF_URL), which will work.