# How to render pdf/doc/img in reactjs component

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a reactjs project which has some files stored in the AWS s3 bucket. So when I try to view those files via iframe it doesn't get loaded & also I tried react-file-viewer package then it will give me errors of memory overflow and app crash.

Below is the file which I'm trying to download as a sample : https://ciao-live.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/CIAO_ERP/Documents/CustomerDocuments/1581489168529-pdf-sample.pdf

How can I solve this?

### Update

I have got a solution unfortunately, this won't work for my AWS files, it will only download the files when it's in AWS S3 bucket:

```
 <object            width="100%"
                    height="100%"
                    data="https://ciao-live.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/CIAO_ERP/Documents/CustomerDocuments/1581489168529-pdf-sample.pdf"
                    type="application/pdf"
                  >
                    File Load Fails!
                  </object>
```

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596329/display-pdf-in-reactjs

Comment: thank you! i have tried  <object width="100%" height="400" data="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" type="application/pdf">   </object> which is working :)

Comment: unfortunately, this won't work,it will only download the files when it's in aws s3bucket: <object
                    width="100%"
                    height="100%"
                    data="https://ciao-live.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/CIAO_ERP/Documents/CustomerDocuments/1581489168529-pdf-sample.pdf"
                    type="application/pdf"
                  >
                    File Load Fail!
                  </object>  please help me to solve this! Thanks So much!

Comment: i have solved it, problem is on aws where im uploading the file it forogot to set content type , after i set it files are opening without any problem..

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code. only this help for image

```
import img from "../../assets/img/logo(name).svg"; //Try to import your image using AWS s3 bucket

   render() {
        return (
            <div className="content" style={{ overflow: "auto"}}>
                 <img id="logo-img" src={img} alt="logo" /> 
            </div>
       )
    }
```

Comment: thank you! I have fixed with the image but still struggling on pdf & docs. I have tried iframe but it will automatically download the pdf file.