# how can i display a buffer data as Pdf Document in my react app?

Tags: node.js, react-pdf

I'm trying to display a document file and download it in pdf in React,
the document is uploaded it a file I used express-file-upload to do that, but I don't know how to fetch the document and display it in my react app,
this is how my data look like :

```
{
  "Document": {
    "type": "Buffer",
    "data": [91, 111, 98, 106, 101, 99, 116, 32, 79, 98, 106, 101, 99, 116, 93]
  },
}
```

Comment: Is your data Buffer a vaild pdf file ? or what type of binary is it ?

Comment: @Marc, its text file

Comment: And what has this to do with a pdf file ? do you want to generate a pdf document from that data ?

Comment: yes, that's what  I'm trying   to do I couldn't figure out how to do it

Comment: Have you read @Isolated answer ?!
Take a look on the react-pdf link. In the first chapter (tl dr) is your solution mentioned.
Create a base64 string from your buffer and display it via "react-pdf".

Answer (score 1):

```js
const Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;

const buff = Buffer.from('something cool');
console.log(buff);
console.log(buff.toString());
```

Call `.toString()` on the Buffer object, this will convert it into a string value.

```
<Buffer 73 6f 6d 65 74 68 69 6e 67 20 63 6f 6f 6c>
something cool
```

- https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

> how can i display a buffer data as Pdf Document in my react app?

With something like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf

I also came across another question that's similar to yours and is using the react-pdf library, I thought it may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45604439/2932298.

Comment: my problem  is I don't know how to display it as a pdf link in my react app

Comment: Are you retrieving it from an Express API? Or is that the part your stuck on? By PDF link, I assume you're looking to add a link the PDF can be downloaded from? Or are you looking to display the PDF in React?

Comment: I really don't know to explain, my app has an admin and a simple user, the user sends a request for leave with a file attachment, the admin receives the request and accepted it my problem is I could it figure how to display the file attachment that sends by the user . and Yes I retrieving from Express Api

Comment: @RiahiRahma have you checked the links at the bottom of my updated answer? That may be relevant to you, assuming you've retrieved the file. Does that help?

Comment: this is how my console in expess show [Document: <Buffer 5b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74 20 4f 62 6a 65 63 74 5d>] and it still the same in my front end