# SharePoint show PDF file outside of SharePoint site for same organization users

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, jwt, microsoft-graph-api

I have Azure app service where users can upload and download the files to/from SharePoint library, now we need to show PDF files in our website.
We can get file download Url, **how can I embed PDF file in my reactjs site, to view the PDF files**.

background
Reactjs calls .Net Core API with jwt token, and API responses new jwt token & library ID for Graph API to access the file, we have give access to one A account and that has access to read and upload the files.
Only PDF file allowed to upload,
Any help appreciated

Comment: If you want to embed PDF file in reactjs then look at the thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596329/display-pdf-in-reactjs

Comment: I am trying to get file in base64 and show in PDF viewer. so far able to get file, convert but when pass it to render it shows on blank PDF file, and correct number of page shown, but not the content. I have tried converting to base64 online (https://base64.guru/converter/decode/pdf) then It works, so I need to do some correction in base64 conversion.

Comment: Cool. Great to hear!!