# How to view a PDF array buffer in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pdf

I am creating a pdf and saving it in node js backend. I want to send this PDF to react. Currently I am converting it to an array buffer and sending the buffer to react, how can I view that file in react?

```
  data = fs.readFileSync(`./userCertificates/${username}.pdf`);
  

  let setSendResponseData = new sendResponseData(data, 200, null);
  let responseToSend = encryptionOfData(setSendResponseData.success()); //I am using encryption on both end
  res.send(responseToSend);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display PDF in reactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596329/display-pdf-in-reactjs)

Comment: You could take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596329/display-pdf-in-reactjs

Comment: No. I am getting errors in packages. Some packages are deprecated

Comment: If none of the prepackaged options happen to work, an alternative would be to implement your own React component built on top of some generic JS solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853898/display-pdf-within-web-browser
Of course, having an out-of-the-box-just-add-water component would be better.